# Set Iframe Src in HTML using C# in Metro?

Tags: c#, html, xaml, iframe, microsoft-metro

I am using a C# project and I have a listbox with a bunch of webpages and I want it so when the user clicks the listbox item, the items URL gets sent to my HTML Pages IFrame Source.

Current HTML FILE

```
<iframe id="Iframe1" type="text/html" src="{C#-Address}" style='position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 999' > </iframe>'
```

As you see, I am trying to get the src to be a value from C#, how can I do that?

Should I open the local HTML file (how?) and search for "{C#-Address}" and replace with the selected SRC Page? Issue I have is... How or what if the page is already loaded but now need to reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did:

```
var goHTML = await Windows.Storage.PathIO.ReadTextAsync("ms-appx:///test.html"); 
string getit = goHTML.ToString();
string News = getit.Replace("ItemFind", "ItemReplace");
MyWebView.NavigateToString(News);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript to get the clicked value on your listbox item and update your iframe src value through it. You don't need any server interaction to this.